# How to extract specific table data (div\tr\td) from multiple URLs in a website in a literate way into CSV (with sample)

Tags: python, html, csv, url

I am learning python and practicing it for extracting data in a public site.
but I found a problem in this learning. I'd like to get your kindly help me out.
Thanks for your help in advance! I will keep track this thread daily to wait for your kindly comments :)

**Purpose:**  
extract all 65 pages' col, row with contents into a csv in one script

**65 pages URLs loop rule:**  
http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo=1  
..........  
http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo=65

**Question1:**  
When running below one page script to extract one page data into csv. I had to run twice with different filename, then data can be extracted to 1st time run file
for example if I run it with test.csv, excel keep 0kb status, after I change filename to test2, then run this script again, after that data can be extract to test.csv..., but test2.csv keep no data with 0 KB. any idea?

**here is one page extract code:**

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = requests.get("http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo=1")
soup = bs(url.content, 'html.parser')
filename = "test.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "iiright")
for div in divs:
         for tr in div.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            data = []
            for td in tr.find_all("td"):
                data.append(td.text.strip())
            if data:
                print("Inserting data: {}".format(','.join(data)))
                csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

**Question2:**
I found problem to literate 65 pages urls to extract data into csv.
it doesn't work... any idea fix it..

**here are 65 pages urls' extract code:**

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo={}"
def get_data(url):
      for url in [url.format(pageNo) for pageNo in range(1,65)]:
        soup = bs(url.content, 'html.parser')
        for div in soup.find_all("div", class_ = "iiright"):
            for tr in div.find_all("tr"):
                data = []
                for td in tr.find_all("td"):
                    data.append(td.text.strip())
                    if data:
                        print("Inserting data: {}".format(','.join(data)))
                        writer.writerow(data)
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
        with open("test.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
            writer = csv.writer(infile)
            get_data(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Just an alternativ approach

Try to keep it simple and may use `pandas`, cause it will do all these things for you under the hood.

1. define a list (data) to keep your results
2. iterate over the urls with `pd.read_html`
3. concat the data frames in `data` and write them `to_csv`or `to_excel`

###### read_html

1. find the table that matches a string -> `match='预售信息查询：'` and select it with `[0]` cause `read_html()` will always give you a list of tables
2. take a special row as header `header =2`
3. get rid of the last row with navigation and last column that is caused by the wrong `colspan` with `.iloc[:-1,:-1]`

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

data = []

for pageNo in range(1,5):
    data.append(pd.read_html(f'http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo={pageNo}', header =2, match='预售信息查询：')[0].iloc[:-1,:-1])

pd.concat(data).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

#### Example (based on your code with function)

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey="

def get_data(url):
    
    data = []

    for pageNo in range(1,2):
        data.append(pd.read_html(f'{url}&pageNo={pageNo}', header=2, match='预售信息查询：')[0].iloc[:-1,:-1])

    pd.concat(data).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data(url)
```

Comment: Thanks HedgeHog for your quick comments! how could be that simple?! --:) actually I tried the code you show in the example and run it by in range(1,2) to try less. unfortunately some error show up... there is no csv file created. 
IndexError: list index out of range
ValueError: Passed header=2 but only 2 lines in file

Comment: It is still working and nothing else as `pd.read_html(f'http://fcjyw.dlhitech.gov.cn/ysxkzList.xhtml?method=doQuery&selYsxk=xmmc&txtkey=&pageNo=1', header=2, match='预售信息查询：')[0].iloc[:-1,:-1]`

Comment: Are you sure, just running the snippet above, without all your code? Added an additionel version, that deals with your function. You have to kick all your csv stuff.

Comment: You really should update your `pandas` 1.3.3 is latest version and also take care of the quotes you are using as shown in your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdx5N.jpg)

Comment: sure, I will update to 1.1.5 version first, seems current python version that I installed can only support to 1.1.5 as latest version. I will try later after upgrade completion. thanks.

Comment: HedgeHog, after upgrade to 1.1.5, it works for me now. thanks a lot for your timely and kindly help!